# Flatlist changes position of renderItem as scroll to more data in horizontal view

Tags: css, react-native, react-native-flatlist

i have map view  on top map view i am rendering `Flatlist` of cards with horizontal scroll which contains 500+ data.
the card is in the bottom is in the center and shows some part of Next and Previous Card but after Scrolling 20 to 30 it start shifting towards the Left side as further, it goes cards are totally misplaced

```
<Animated.FlatList
          ref={scrollView}
          horizontal
          pagingEnabled
          decelerationRate={0}
          getItemLayout={(data, index) => ({
            length: CARD_WIDTH,
            offset: (CARD_WIDTH + 20) * index,
            index,
          })}
          scrollEventThrottle={1}
          onScrollToIndexFailed={() => {}}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          snapToInterval={CARD_WIDTH + 20}//CARD_WIDTH = 310 AND 20  IS MARGIN
          snapToAlignment="center"
          style={styles.scrollView}
          contentInset={{
            top: 0,
            left: SPACING_FOR_CARD_INSET,//SPACING_FOR_CARD_INSET=width - (CARD_WIDTH+20)/2
            bottom: 0,
            right: SPACING_FOR_CARD_INSET,
          }}
          contentContainerStyle={{
            paddingHorizontal:
              Platform.OS === 'android' ? SPACING_FOR_CARD_INSET : 0,
          }}
          onScroll={Animated.event(
            [
              {
                nativeEvent: {
                  contentOffset: {
                    x: mapAnimation,
                  },
                },
              },
            ],
            {useNativeDriver: true},
          )}
          data={stationData}
          renderItem={renderPromotionItem}
          scrollsToTop={false}
          
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        />
```

Comment: this logic work with limited array size you need to Adjust flatlist layout